# js destructuring assignment not work in while loop

Tags: javascript, destructuring

`[a,b] = [b, a+b]` here not work , a b always 0 and 1.

If use a temp variable to swap the value ,that works.

```js
function fibonacciSequence() {
  let [a, b, arr] = [0, 1, []]
  while (a <= 255) {
    arr.concat(a)
    [a, b] = [b, a + b]
    console.log(a, b) // always 0 1
  }
}
console.log(fibonacciSequence())
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: What do you expect `arr.concat(a)[a, b]` to mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Automatic Semicolon Insertion isn't doing what you expect. It's not adding a semicolon between

```
arr.concat(a)
```

and

```
[a, b] = [b, a + b]
```

so it's being treated as if you wrote

```
arr.concat(a)[a, b] = [b, a + b]
```

Add all the semicolons explicitly and you get a correct result.

```js
function fibonacciSequence() {
  let [a, b, arr] = [0, 1, []];
  while (a <= 255) {
    arr.concat(a);
    [a, b] = [b, a + b];
    console.log(a, b); // always 0 1
  }
}
console.log(fibonacciSequence())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function as well:

```
    function fibonacciSequence() {
      let [a, b] = [0, 1];
      while (a <= 255) {

       b = a + b;
       a = b - a;
       console.log(a,b);
      }
    }
    fibonacciSequence();
```